# Golang - go run takes long to execute

Tags: performance, go

I have a little problem, where every time I run 'go run >filename<' after making changes to my problem, it takes many seconds to start executing.

I tried it with a simple program like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Output")
}
```

And it took about 18 seconds to print out the result.

And ideas on what could cause this problem?

I am on windows by the way.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is probably building dependencies. Try `go install` first to build your package and its dependencies. After that, `go run` should be much faster.

Comment: Tried that, but every time I execute 'go run' after that, it either produces the same output, no matter which changes I make to the source code or just recompiles it, which leads to the executing taking so long again.

Comment: Do you know how much time takes the execution of that specific line ? Maybe you can add a timer to see where is the problem.. (https://coderwall.com/p/cp5fya/measuring-execution-time-in-go)

Comment: I'm also facing this issue on my 32GB Windows 10 machine

Answer (score 14):

Found this while experiencing an identical issue with freshly-compiled golang binaries on MacOS (OSX) Catalina.

In short, the OS now scans a new (to it) binary for malware, it usually does it on first start, but I found that it was doing it 3-5 times in a row, after which the binary got whitelisted and started as normal. Obviously, once you make changes to the code and re-compile the scans start happening again. The scan would take upwards of 20 seconds which ruined golangs fast iteration cycle.

Solution for me was as follows:

```
sudo spctl developer-mode enable-terminal
```

Then go to Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy

In the list to the left you will now have "Developer Tools" section, which will have OSX built-in Terminal listed. Check the box to enable it, and/or add anything else you may be using to develop (iTerm, VS Code, etc)

When running binaries from those applications the scans stop and things go back to normal.

Comment: also, a restart was required for me to make it work

Answer (score 4):

`$ go run` command always complies the code into a temporary binary file and then executes it, every time it is run.

To go around this you could do `$ go build -i main.go` which will compile dependencies separately as `.a` files (i'm guessing this is the part that takes the longest because it takes time to build the dependencies) and then execute it with `$ ./main`, and each execution should be faster that `$ go run`.

You could also run a `$ go get -u ./...` to update all your deps and building with the -x flag will show you if the toolchain is finding incompatible versions.

`$ go install` builds the command in a temporary directory then moves it to $GOPATH/bin so you can execute it without the path `$ main`.

The last two commands require a rebuild/reinstall if the code has changes.

Comment: This seems to help a bit. However, I discovered that the code only runs slow on the very first execution of the build. Any reason for that?

Comment: with `go run` or executing the binary?

Comment: with 'go run'. After making changes to the program and running it once, if the code doesn't change 'go run' will keep being quick. I actually tried the same with running some c code, and discovered the exact same behaviour, so 'go' might not be the problem in this case...

Comment: According to the doc of 1.18.2, `The -i flag installs the packages that are dependencies of the target. The -i flag is deprecated. Compiled packages are cached automatically. `

Answer (score 4):

If anyone still facing this issue on windows. you can fix it in 2 ways. it works 100%.

open virus & threat protection in windows security in settings

**way 1**:
turn off real-time protection

**way 2**:
in virus and threat protection settings(click on manage settings) go to exclusions and add the following three folders

1. `C:\Users\anves\AppData\Local\go-build`
2. `C:\Users\anves\AppData\Local\Temp`
3. `The folder where go is installed.`